# Master's degree in linguistics

Tags: cross-linguistic, language-acquisition

I am a student of Translation Studies (Slovene-German and English-German translation) from the University of Ljubljana, currently in my final year of bachelor's degree. At the time I'm in the process of choosing the right master's degree and I hope I could get some help and suggestions regarding my situation.

I have always been very interested in learning about new cultures, which is why I've always had an easy time picking up additional languages. I come from a small country where learning new languages is seen as very beneficial for finding a job. During my education I had the opportunity to learn Italian (studied it for thee years), English (learning since I was seven) German (started in high school) Croatian (which I mostly learned from my Croatian relatives) and Latin (studied it for three years in high school). During high school I also learned some French in hopes of being able to understand old French songs and literature. I should stress that I never see language learning as an obligation, but rather as a really unique and rewarding activity. I find it especially fun to be able to converse with foreigners or use these languages while I travel. It seems very interesting that the learning process gradually got easier with every language I learned.

After I began studying translation at the university, I decided to try something completely new, so I began learning Japanese. I'm happy to say that I'm doing quite well, just a month ago I finished a free B1 language course on my Erasmus exchange in Germany and now I'm hoping to travel to Japan in the future. Every day I try expanding my vocabulary through watching Youtube videos or rewaching anime without the subtitles. A year ago I also began studying Mandarin Chinese which has been the hardest to learn so far, but I'm practicing with a friend who is a native speaker.

During my first three years of university I learned how to translate English and German texts into Slovene and vice versa, but I also had courses connected to linguistics in general, as well as the linguistics of those three languages. However as I was learning, I gradually realised that I am much more interested in studying the process of language learning and how language and culture are interconnected. For example, studying Japanese and Mandarin gave me a whole new perspective on East Asian cultures, which I would very much like to explore more. So far it has been hard for me to decide on the right master's degree, as well as choosing a profession where I could use my skills and interests to my advantage. The areas I am most interested in are: the process of langauge aquisition, studying and comparing features of various languages, language revitalization, studying how culture and language are connected and studying East Asian languages in general. I also enjoy travelling and living abroad.

If you have any suggestions on what master's degree I should look into (which university or courses I could choose), I would be very thankful. I would also be very grateful for advice on what career I could pursue in the future. So far I've had a hard time deciding which areas I should focus on.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of question is not really answerable and we don't give advice here. You could raise such a question in the chat but you need some reputation points to participate there.

Comment: Hi, David, and welcome. I suggest you contact a bunch of professors at your university, for instance. If you are doing a bachelor's thesis, I am sure your advisor can guide you with the process!

Comment: The question you should ask yourself first is what you are going to do with this degree, why you think you might need it.

Comment: Consider asking about graduate options in Academia Stack Exchange: https://academia.stackexchange.com/